# javascript:add behavior to method via prototype - infiltrate code

Tags: javascript, methods, interceptor, control-flow, modifier

We have the following situation, we use a library to encrypt stuff, I want to know if we can change the parameters before they are encrypted. I can easily do this:

`MyEncoder.prototype.encode = (value) => {//change it the way I want};`

but, how do I do to make it do what it used to do, before I changed it? (**I know!!!**)

This won't work: `var encoder = MyEncoder.prototype.encode;` because it will copy only the method, it won't have `this` and, well, you know.

If I could debug the `encode` method. That'd help!

Comment: try this `MyEncoder.prototype.original_encode = MyEncoder.prototype.encode`

Comment: Do not use arrow functions for methods! Use a real `function` where `this` is available, where you can `.call()` the original method with the proper this argument.

Comment: ... as for the OP's underlying problem which is _**method modification**_ ... there should be, at one day in addition to `Function.prototype.bind`, native support for *method modifiers* like `Function.prototype[before|after|around|afterThrowing|afterFinally]` that provides bullet proof abstraction levels for this kind of tasks.

Answer (score 1):

Write an *Immediately Invoked Function Expression* (IIFE) that 1-stly preserves the original prototypal `encode` functionality within the closure it does create and 2-ndly returns your own implementation of `encode` which is now in control of the passed arguments and the return value of the original `encode`. Thus one has written kind of an **`around` *method modifier*** ...

```js
MyEncoder.prototype.encode = (function /*create_around_modifier*/ (proto_encode) {
  return function /*modified_encode*/ (...argsArray) {

    // - intercept data flow ...
    //   ... e.g. look into or change the passed arguments.

    // ... implement the **before** part.

    // - call/invoke the original encode ...
    //
    // return value after invoking the original `encode`.
    const result = proto_encode.apply(this, argsArray);

    // - intercept data flow ...
    //   ... e.g. look at, work with or change the result.

    // ... implement the **after** part.

    //
    // - do not forget the return value.
  };
}(MyEncoder.prototype.encode));
```

Answer (score 0):

Real example, than:

```
JSON.stringify = (function (proto_method) {
  return function (...args) {
    //I can to whatever I want before original method does it's job

    return proto_method.apply(this, args);
  };
}(JSON.stringify));
```

So than I can easily change a parameter, maybe check what's done before encrypting something, given that JSON is largely used for dealing with kind of scenario.

Thanks everyone.

Comment: ... well, almost. Since `stringify` is a static method nailed to the `JSON` namespace, its implementation does not depend/relay on any bound `this` context. As for your example, `.apply(null, args)` would be equally fine.

Comment: That's what I found weird. I guess I might take some time to study namespaces in JS lol. Thanks